# Question about formulating a problem as a Linear Program

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming

I have the following problem:

We have 180 students. Each student is required to choose one of 6 courses to get a degree. No course should have more than 30 students in it. Moreover, students must specify three courses with different preferences :[image: pij = [0, 100]].
The goal is to find an assignment  of students to courses in such a way that:

- Every student is assigned to a course.
- There is no course which has more than 30 students.
- The sum of student preferences is maximized.

First question is to formulate the problem as a Linear Program (LP). My formulation is as follows:

Maximize [image: \sum_{i, j} x_{i, j} p_{i, j}],

subject to:

- [image: x_{i, j} \in { 0, 1 }].
- [image: \sum_{j = 0}^{5} x_{i, j} = 1, \forall i].
- [image: \sum_{i = 0}^{179} x_{i, j} = 30, \forall j].

Is my formulation correct ?

The second part of the question is the following:

Suppose we have a black box which solves the Min Cost Flow problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem). How to use this black box to solve our assignment problem ?

Thank you,

Regards.

Comment: Note that this is **I**nteger Linear Programming (ILP), not just *linear* programming. Furthermore I think that you probably want to use sum_i xij <= 30, not sum_i xij = 30?

Comment: What have you tried on the second part?

Answer (score 1):

Your ***I***nteger Linear Programming (ILP) formulation is not completely correct, in your last constraint, you write that all classes have exactly 30 students, but that is incorrect, a class can not have more than 30 students.

So the formulation should be something like:

maximize *∑<sub>ij</sub> x<sub>ij</sub> p<sub>ij</sub>*
subject to:
    *∑<sub>j</sub>x<sub>ij</sub>=1, ∀i*
    ***∑<sub>i</sub>x<sub>ij</sub>≤30, ∀j***

As for the max-flow, you can present each student as a node in a network, and each class as a node, for example for four students and three classes, the graph looks like:

[image: example network with four students and three classes]

Here the capacity of *s* to the students *s<sub>i</sub>* is *1*, since each student can make at most one choice, so *c(s, s<sub>i</sub>)=1*. The capacity of a class room is 30, so that means that for every class *c<sub>j</sub>*, it holds that *c(c<sub>i</sub>, d)=30*. Furthermore the capacity between each *s<sub>i</sub>* and *c<sub>j</sub>* is 1 as well (although a larger capacity will not make a difference), so *c(s<sub>i</sub>, c<sub>j</sub>)=1*.

Here we add a "*cost*" to the edges between *s<sub>i</sub>* and *c<sub>j</sub>* that is equal to *a(s<sub>i</sub>, c<sub>j</sub>)=-p<sub>ij</sub>*, so given the perference is higher, the cost is lower. Other edges have a cost of zero, so *a(s, s<sub>i</sub>)=a(c<sub>j</sub>,d)=0*. So here we will assign flows (based on the capacity one per student, such that the total flow to a class room is less than 30), and minimize the cost, so minimize the sum of the *-p<sub>ij</sub>*'s. Given a flow exists such that there is a flow of 1 from the source *s* to every student *s<sub>i</sub>*, then we can give each student a choice, and the total cost will be optimized.

Comment: But one of the constraints we have is that every student should be assigned to a course. We have 180 students in total and 6 courses. This means that every course has 30 students exactly.

Comment: @HusseinHammoud: correct, but a *literal* translation is a less than or equal, it is typically better to encode the exact logic, since parameters can slightly change. It also makes the "program" easily reuseable in case the number of students changes.